# WebApi Reference Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm using webapi service into Mvc I had created a reference of Api to mvc but after writing the code I'm getting this error

> The type 'System.Web.Http.ApiController' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I also installed this package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 5.2.3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assembly `System.Web.Http` is in package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.
You have to save all files and then run `update-package -reinstall System.Web.Http`. Script runed after installing will add refernce to this assembly to you project (it will be saved in .csproj). And then save all files again (needed to save project file).

Reference in .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

E.g. in empty project after `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` you will have modification in packages.config and in .csproj files.

If you will close project right after performing install command and choose no to save changes, then you will see this error again.